# mysql slave restore database ERROR 3079

Tags: mysql

- Master A mysql 8
- Master B mysql 5.7
- Master C mysql 5.7
- Slave mysql 8

i create 4 channels on my slave and i can not restore backup from master.

```
[root@CentOS-76-64-minimal hex]# gunzip < db.gz | mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 3079 (HY000) at line 22: Multiple channels exist on the slave. Please provide channel name as an argument.
```

Comment: 3 Masters in a circle?  Ugh.

Comment: 3 different master and one slave (for backup)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
mysql> create database mydb;
mysql> use mydb;
mysql> source db_backup.dump;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to DBA.  Answers that don't explain why they work are generally not well received. You might want to read https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you this works. 
gunzip db.gz after load database.